# Disable output of process after timeout in command prompt

Tags: batch-file, cmd, console, windows-console

I need to execute a batch script from inside the Command Prompt in such a way that the **output of the script would stop showing up after 6 seconds** (without clearing the screen), but the script would still be kept running. I am unable to modify the mentioned batch script.

Is there a command for this? Is this possible?

Comment: This is screaming [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me. Why are you trying to do this? Also, my initial reaction was "no, it's not possible," but then I started thinking about file redirection to alternate streams and now I can't completely discount the possibility.

Comment: For do this, needs know the position of line and the column that you wants stop showing output, this for sure, that not answer a one not one satisfied answer. Sorry my limited English.